# Read files with fileinput.input() from X line

Tags: python, file-io

here my question, it is probably not very complex but I am learning Python. I'm trying to read multiple files (all of them with the same format), at the same time a have to begin reading them from line 32, somehow I don't find the most efficient way to do so.

Here my code until now:

```
for file in fileinput.input():
    entries = [f.strip().split("\t") for f in file].readlines()[32:]
```

which gives the error: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'readlines'

I know another possibility would be:

```
sources = open(sys.argv[1], "r").readlines()[32:]
```

and then just on the command line python3.2 script.py data/*.csv. But this seems not to work properly.

I am thanked for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `openhook` argument.

According to [the module documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/fileinput.html):

> You can control how files are opened by providing an opening hook via
>   the openhook parameter to `fileinput.input()` or `FileInput()`. The hook
>   must be a function that takes two arguments, filename and mode, and
>   returns an accordingly opened file-like object. Two useful hooks are
>   already provided by this module.

```
import fileinput

def skip32(filename, mode):
    f = open(filename, mode)
    for i in range(32):
        f.readline()
    return f

entries = [line.strip().split('\t') for line in fileinput.input(openhook=skip32)]
```

BTW, the last line can be replaced with (using [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html) module):

```
import csv
entries = list(csv.reader(fileinput.input(openhook=skip32), delimiter='\t'))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer falsetru! I was wondering if it is possible to read multiple files always from an specific line with this same method, i.e., the files a I have are very messy and the information I need is not always at the same line (32), but they all contain the right information at some point. How can I read them from , for example a line where I find an specific pattern, like ID[tab]NAME[tand]GEO[tab]FEATURE. Is this somehow possible?

Comment: @El_Patrón, I don't understand what you mean. How about post a separated question?

Comment: @El_Patrón, As I said it's hard to understand your new question. How about put real examples (if file are big, upload it somewhere and give us URL to download them).

Comment: @El_Patrón, Beside that, your update is contradict with your original question; which make answers invalid. Please post the updated part as a separated question.

Comment: Ok, I will, it's may be better!

Answer (score 0):

It's just a little syntax

```
 entries = [f.strip().split("\t") for f in file].readlines()[32:]
```

should be:

```
entries = [f.strip().split("\t") for f in file.readlines()][32:]
```

Comment: Thank you Vincent, unfortunately I get the error: AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'readlines'

Comment: Then file is not a file object but a string. What does file represent?

Comment: they are 10 tab-separated files (with format .csv), The files contain tab-separated strings. I am trying to open and read them from command line as: python3.2 script.py data/*.csv, since I need to open all of them and loop